# Data analysis/manipulation in excel

Tags: excel

I'm new to excel and this might be a beginner question so please bear with me, I'm trying to do the following:
If I have some data in an excel sheet which goes like this -

-- Running case : 03_mileage.cry ......
Result : OK
-- Running case : 07_option mode.cry ......
Result : OK
-- Running case : 10_80 columns.cry ......
Result : OK
-- Running case : 11_Split tag.cry ......
Result : OK
-- Running case : 12_TQC.cry ......
Result : ERROR

What I want is to move this to another sheet with the Case in one column and the result in the corresponding column.
I would prefer using excel formulaes over VB.
Thanks,
Abhinaya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first sheet (Sheet1) looks like this:

```
A1:  -- Running case : 03_mileage.cry ......
A2:  Result : OK
A3:  -- Running case : 07_option mode.cry ......
A4:  Result : OK
A5:  -- Running case : 10_80 columns.cry ......
A6:  Result : OK
A7:  -- Running case : 11_Split tag.cry ......
A8:  Result : OK
A9:  -- Running case : 12_TQC.cry ......
A10: Result : ERROR
```

Then, on the new spreadsheet ( within the same workbook ) you can refer to the range of another worksheet like this:

```
A1: =Sheet1!A1          B1: =Sheet1!A2
A2: =Sheet1!A3          B2: =Sheet1!A4
A3: =Sheet1!A5          B3: =Sheet1!A6
A4: =Sheet1!A7          B4: =Sheet1!A8
A5: =Sheet1!A9          B5: =Sheet1!A10
```

on so on...

---

Alternatively, if there is lots of data in your first sheet, you could use [VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to do the job.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CaseDesc()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr&, i&, nxt&
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lr = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    nxt = 1
    ' if you have headers change 1 to 2 ( or row where your data starts)
    For i = 1 To lr
        If i Mod 2 Then
            ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
        Else
            ws2.Range("B" & ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```